# How to add a new element to a sequence with a EOL comment

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml, ordereddictionary, ruamel.yaml

I have a YAML file as

```
# This is the group manages the permissions
group:
  - state: present
    group:
    name: "Developers"
    description: "The development team"
    userNames:
      - userl1  # <user1Name> - <User1email>
      - userd2  # <user2Name> - <User2email>
      - userr1  # <user3Name> - <User3email>
  - state: present
    group:
    name: "Admins"
    description: "The Admin team"
    userNames:
      - userl1  # <user1Name> - <User1email>
      - userd2  # <user2Name> - <User2email>
```

I want to add a new user to developer whose id is `usermd` with comment in line `# <UserName> - <Useremail>`
similarly to the admin group too.

expected output as:

```
# This is the group manages the permissions
group:
  - state: present
    group:
    name: "Developers"
    description: "The development team"
    userNames:
      - userl1  # <user1Name> - <User1email>
      - userd2  # <user2Name> - <User2email>
      - userr1  # <user3Name> - <User3email>
      - usermd  # <usermdName, Surname> - <Usermdemail>
  - state: present
    group:
    name: "Admins"
    description: "The Admin team"
    userNames:
      - userl1  # <user1Name> - <User1email>
      - userd2  # <user2Name> - <User2email>
```

The code I have used is

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

with open('Access.yaml', 'r') as f:
    # Load the YAML data
    yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML(typ='rt')
    data = yaml.load(f)

for x in data['jfrog']['groups']:
    if not x["group"]["name"].endswith('Developers'):
        continue
    usr = x['group']['userNames']
    usr.append('usermd')

yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

I am using a jfrog yaml so the jfrog is parent key for the repositories
I haven't found a way to wrap the comment to the new user.
but when I use this the output I got as

````
    group:
      name: Developers
      description: The development group
      autoJoin: false
      userNames:
      - userl1      # <user1Name> - <User1email>
      - userd2      # <user2Name> - <User2email>
      - userr1      # <user3Name> - <User3email>
      - usermd
  - state: present
      # This is the Admins group need to be added
    group:
      name: Admins
      description: The admin group
      autoJoin: false
      userNames:
      - userl1      # <user1Name> - <User1email>
      - userd2      # <user2Name> - <User2email>```
````

Comment: You just add a new elment to `data['group'][0]['userNames']` and set the comment for that element. Where is your code trying to do this? Without it we can't point out what you are doing wrong nor make sure you don't assume SO is a code writing service.

Comment: @Anthon I have added the code snippet, but the file "Access.yaml" is the one contains the entire yaml and I have inserted only the part I am focused to edit now. if there is a way to upload the entire file, please let me know, I can't add the entire one here since it isaround 100 line

Answer (score 0):

The sequence and its elements are loaded in a `CommentedSeq` which behaves like a Python
list, but also contains the comments. You can inspect its `.ca` attribute
to see what the comments on the existing lines look like and create an
extra comment item for the added entry:

```py
import sys
from pathlib import Path
import ruamel.yaml

path = Path('Access.yaml')

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.indent(mapping=4, sequence=4, offset=2)
yaml.preserve_quotes = True
data = yaml.load(path)

for x in data['group']:
    if not x["name"].endswith('Developers'):
        continue
    users = x['userNames']
    # print(users.ca)  # to check how the other comments are set
    key = len(users)  # index of the next item
    users.append('usermd') # add the item
    # create and set the comment
    mark = ruamel.yaml.error.CommentMark(16)
    comment = ruamel.yaml.tokens.CommentToken('# <usermdName, Surname> - <Usermdemail>', mark, None)
    users.ca.items[key] = [comment, None, None, None]

yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
# This is the group manages the permissions
group:
  - state: present
    group:
    name: "Developers"
    description: "The development team"
    userNames:
      - userl1  # <user1Name> - <User1email>
      - userd2  # <user2Name> - <User2email>
      - userr1  # <user3Name> - <User3email>
      - usermd  # <usermdName, Surname> - <Usermdemail>
  - state: present
    group:
    name: "Admins"
    description: "The Admin team"
    userNames:
      - userl1  # <user1Name> - <User1email>
      - userd2  # <user2Name> - <User2email>
```

Comment: Thanks, Anthon I will try this. Where can I find extra arguments or fields that exist in the library? I will try to look into them once before raising another question similar to this.

Comment: I should have written that these are internal routines that `ruamel.yaml` uses to preserve comments. There is no documentation for those except for the source code, and expect these to change, so pin the version number of `ruamel.yaml` that you use.

Comment: I use currently the latest version 0.17.21.